# using mdadm, can I add a mirror raid over network for backup purposes?

Tags: software-raid

I have a remote live filesystem I want to make a snapshot of.

- Using mondo it could work but it slows down the system too much.
- Using dump/restore could work too but I don't seem to get file permissions correctly

The partitions I want to make a snapshot of are raid-1 mirrors so I'm thinking I could maybe add another mirror but remotely and when it is finally in sync, disconnect and then I have my snapshot.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement Raid-1 over network, you can try [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/home/what-is-drbd/), but I think (for your requirements) you just need to have a file system which supports snapshots.

Comment: yes.. but I can't switch the system to using lvm2 for example because it would take too long and I can't shut it down for that long =(

Comment: Then you should make sure you have good backups - all single-servers fail, and if you cannot schedule an outage then you'll find a world of pain sooner or later.